# Tuple matching in Scala: 'match' failing to match returned tuple (Future, Json)

Tags: json, scala, pattern-matching

I've written a utility class to help with unit testing. One function, fakeRequest(), will process a request, parse the response, validate the JSON, and make sure things went well in general. It then returns a tuple of `(response, parsedJSON)` to the caller. If things go poorly, it returns a `failure`.

This all works fine, but I can't figure out how to match on the returned tuple.

What I want:
1. If I get `(response, parsedJSON)` validate the response;
2. If I get `failure`, fail the test case.

My `fakeRequest()` looks like this:

```
def fakeRequest[A, B](target: () => Call, request: A, response: B)(implicit f1: Format[A], f2: Format[B]) = {
    route(FakeRequest(target()).withJsonBody(Json.toJson(request))) match {
        case Some(response) => {
            contentType(response) must beSome("application/json")
            charset(response) must beSome("utf-8")

            GPLog(s"fakeRequest: HTTP status ${status(response)}: JSON response: ${contentAsString(response)}")
            val parsedJSON = Json.parse(contentAsString(response)).validate[B]

            (response, parsedJSON)
        }
        case _ => failure
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to match on the `response`. I've tried a couple dozen variations and can't get it to match **on a `response`**:

```
fakeRequest(controllers.routes.GPInviteService.invite, test, GPInviteService.InviteResponse(true, None, None)) match {
    case (response, JsSuccess(invite: GPInviteService.InviteResponse, _)) => { // Never matches
        status(response) must beEqualTo(UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        invite.inviteSent must beFalse
        invite.error.get.code must beEqualTo(GPError.ValidationFailed.code)
    }
    case e: JsError => failure
    ...
```

This invariably **does not work.** However, and this is what is really confusing me, *I can return the response status code, just not the `response` object itself.* E.g., if I change `fakeRequest` as such:

```
def fakeRequest[A, B](target: () => Call, request: A, response: B)(implicit f1: Format[A], f2: Format[B]) = {
    route(FakeRequest(target()).withJsonBody(Json.toJson(request))) match {
        case Some(response) => {
            // ...
            (status(response), parsedJSON) // return status, not response?
        }
        case _ => failure
    }
}
```

I can test against the `status` just fine, and everything works as expected:

```
fakeRequest(controllers.routes.GPInviteService.invite, test, GPInviteService.InviteResponse(true, None, None)) match {
    case (status, JsSuccess(response: GPInviteService.InviteResponse, _)) => { // Matches!
        status must beEqualTo(UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        response.inviteSent must beFalse
        response.error.get.code must beEqualTo(GPError.ValidationFailed.code)
    }
    case e: JsError => failure
}
```

I'd love to understand why I can match a simple status code, but I can't match a more complex object.

FYI, I even tried `case (a, b) => println(a)` just to see what would happen. It didn't match when returning the `response`.

Comment: This looks like Scala timesink #34: no type declarations.  When something doesn't work right in this sort of way, make sure your inputs are what you think they are.  I don't know if that's the problem, but I'd surely check it before anything else.  If you're using an IDE, it can help a lot (in Intellij, alt-enter on thing to add type to; not sure about Eclipse).

Comment: What is the response type ? Which library you are using for the Http Request and Response ?